# Why can't I substitute $u=ie^{-it}$ on integral $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2} (e^{-2it}+1)^x\ln(e^{2it}+1)dt$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, substitution

I wanted to use substitution $u=ie^{-it}$ to simplify following integral: $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2} (e^{-2it}+1)^x\ln(e^{2it}+1)dt$$
After substituting I got following integral:
$$i\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(1-u^2)^x\ln(1-\frac{1}{u^2})}{u}du$$
This is the integral of the odd function over symmetric interval and therefore it is equal to $0$. However this is not proper result (For example when $x=1$ the integral should be equal to $\pi$).
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first integral, when $t$ is from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ via $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $ie^{-2it}$ is from $-1$ via $i$ to $1$. However $u$ is from $-1$ via $0$ to $1$ in the second integral. They go through different paths. They coincide only under certain conditions.

Comment: But there is no problem with using DI on complex integrals right?

Comment: I do not get the meaning of `DI'. Complex integral always is on some curve. If you do not know which curve you go through. You do not know the integral value. However, if you calculate a complex integral $\int_\gamma f(z) dz$, where $f$ is a holomorphic function. It do not depend on the curve $\gamma$ since Cauchy integal theorem. That is, if $\alpha$ is another curve with $\gamma(0)=\alpha(0)$ and $\gamma(1)=\alpha(1)$ then $\beta:=\gamma\alpha^{-1}$ is a close cruve. By Cauchy integal theorem, $\int_\beta f(z) dz$. It implies that $\int_\alpha f(z) dz=\int_\gamma f(z) dz$.